# How detect css3 transition end event

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, mousewheel, transition

So, I want to create a vertical slider which works on `mousewheel` event. Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="projects">
    <section id="project-0" class="slide" style="background-color: #000000;"></section>
    <section id="project-1" class="slide" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;"></section>
    <section id="project-2" class="slide" style="background-color: #eeeeee"></section>
</div>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
#projects {
  width: 100%
}
#projects .slide {
  position: absolute;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.64, 0.3, 1);
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.64, 0.3, 1);
  -o-transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.64, 0.3, 1);
  transition: height 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.64, 0.3, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0)
}  
  #projects .slide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 0;
  background-size: auto 90%
}

#projects .slide:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 10
}

#projects .slide:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 9
}

#projects .slide:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 8
}

#projects .slide:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 7
}
#projects .slide.no-animation {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important
}

#projects .slide.active {
  height: 100%
}
```

and the javascript code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.fullScreenSlider  = function(){
        var parentDiv = $("#projects");
        var  slides = parentDiv.children();
        var  i = 0;
        var doMouseWheel = true;
        $(slides).each(function(){
          $(this).on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(event) {
                console.log("set doMouseEvent true");
                doMouseWheel = true;
            });
        });
        function init(){
            $("body").removeClass("shifted").css("overflow","hidden");
            $(slides).addClass("active");
            scrollEventListener();
        }
        function scrollEventListener(){
            $(window).unbind().bind("mousewheel",function(event){
                var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || event.wheelDelta;
                if (doMouseWheel && delta >= 0) {
                    doMouseWheel = false;
                    console.log("Scroll up");
                    $(slides[i]).addClass("active");
                    i--;
                }
                if(doMouseWheel && delta < 0) {
                    doMouseWheel = false;
                    console.log("Scroll down");
                    $(slides[i]).removeClass("active");
                    i++;
                }
                if(i + 1 == $(slides).length){
                    $("body").addClass("shifted").css("overflow","auto");
                }else{
                    $("body").removeClass("shifted").css("overflow","hidden");

                }
                return false;
            })
        }
        init();
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("#projects").fullScreenSlider();
});
```

I use doMouseWheel variable to prevent multiple slide animation. But there is problem with detecting css3 transition end, because it does not work properly. So how can I detect end of css animation to allow animation again or detect mousewheel event end?

Comment: What do you mean when you state "it does not work properly"? Does the event fire? Are you certain your handlers have been bound and that they've been bound to the correct events?

Comment: it seems that the transition end does not work, because the two slide were animating at the same time. I want to get effect like on http://www.hugeinc.com/ website